# How can I combine text resizing with bolding in footer?

Tags: php, phpword

I can alternate bold and normal text in a footer (thanks to [ejuhjav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111397/ejuhjav)) but only if I don't try to style the text.

In the following example, the letter 'T' comes out bold because it's at the default size (12).

If I reduce the text, the bolding is dropped. I've also tried using named font styles and created font style objects. No luck.

Is there something simple I'm missing?

```
// create footer
$footer = $section->addFooter();
$textrun = $footer->addTextRun();

// define bold style
$boldFontStyleName = 'BoldText';
$phpWord->addFontStyle($boldFontStyleName, array('bold' => true));

// add content
$textrun->addText('T', $boldFontStyleName);
$textrun->addText(' ++353 1 555 0001 ',  
    array('name' => 'Helvetica', 'size' => 8));
$textrun->addText('E',   
    array('name' => 'Helvetica', 'size' => 8),  $boldFontStyleName);
$textrun->addText(' abc.def@ghk.ie ',  
    array('name' => 'Helvetica', 'size' => 8));
$textrun->addText('W',   
    array('name' => 'Helvetica', 'size' => 8),  $boldFontStyleName);
$textrun->addText(' abcd.ie/wxz',  
    array('name' => 'Helvetica', 'size' => 8));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and here goes the third time then :)

the addText function definition is:

```
addText(string $text, mixed $fStyle = null, mixed $pStyle = null)
```

i.e. the font styles are given with the second parameter and thus the rows where you have the `$boldFontStyleName` variable as third attribute the font is not bolded.

The easiest way to fix this would be to to just define couple of additional font styles:

```
// create footer
$footer = $section->addFooter();
$textrun = $footer->addTextRun();

// define font styles
$boldFontStyleName = 'BoldText';
$phpWord->addFontStyle($boldFontStyleName, array('bold' => true));

$smallFontStyleName = 'smallText';
$phpWord->addFontStyle($smallFontStyleName, array(
    'name' => 'Helvetica',
    'size' => 8,
));

$boldSmallFontStyleName = 'BoldSmallText';
$phpWord->addFontStyle($boldSmallFontStyleName, array(
    'bold' => true,
    'name' => 'Helvetica',
    'size' => 8,
));

// add content
$textrun->addText('T', $boldFontStyleName);
$textrun->addText(' ++353 1 555 0001 ', $smallFontStyleName); 
$textrun->addText('E', $boldSmallFontStyleName);
$textrun->addText(' abc.def@ghk.ie ', $smallFontStyleName);
$textrun->addText('W', $boldSmallFontStyleName);
$textrun->addText(' abcd.ie/wxz', $smallFontStyleName);
```

Comment: Many thanks again! I am starting to understand order of precedence and over-riding a bit better now, I think. It's a pity there's such a lack of documentation and even a textbook I could use for phpWord. The docs on github etc (https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/phpword/develop/phpword.pdf) list parameters and values but there's little instruction on correct use.

Comment: I've found that best and most up to date 'documentation' how phpword works and what it can do is found under the samples directory of the project [phpword@github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/develop/samples).